# Reusing existing span with custom attributes in CKEditor while changing background color

Tags: ckeditor, custom-data-attribute

When changing the background-color, CKEditor wraps the selected content in a `span` element where the inline style is set.

I have an application to create interactive videos: it is possible to stop the playback in desired moments and, in these pauses, the viewer can jump to key moments of the video, or answer to quizzes, returning to specific points of the video if the answer was wrong, and so on. To create this interactive layer above the player I use the CKEditor with some custom plugins to create the interactive elements.

One of the plugins is used to create `span` elements with a custom attribute `data-player-control`:

```css
span[data-player-control] {
    background-color: #3366FF;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span data-player-control="play">My element</span>
```

The value of the `data-player-control` attribute is not fixed (it can be specified in the plugin), and it is used to control the exhibition of the video.

When the editor is used to change the element background color, it wraps the element text in a new `span`, what results in:

```css
span[data-player-control] {
    background-color: #3366FF;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span data-player-control="play">
  <span style="background-color:#FF0000">My element</span>
</span>
```

These two nested `span` elements, with two distinct background colors, are undesired.

What I need is the inline style to be applied to the existing `span` element, resulting in:

```css
span[data-player-control] {
    background-color: #3366FF;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span data-player-control="play" style="background-color:#FF0000">
  My element
</span>
```

How can this be achieved?

Using dataFilter or htmlFilter is not a feasible solution, as they are executed in input or output data, when entering or existing the inline instance of the CKEditor. Using a transformation also is not a solution, as it uses a simplified form to represent the elements, not the real DOM.

Is there any callback function to use while editing the content (so I can change the DOM according to my needs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to listen to the `change` event in the editor instance and then modify the DOM in `event.editor.ui.contentsElement.$` as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use custom styles definition which is used for adding background-color. The [colorButton_backStyle](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-colorButton_backStyle) can be set in the editor config.

To override span element with some custom attributes, you can use:

```
config.colorButton_backStyle = {
    element: 'span',        
    styles: { 'background-color': '#(color)' },
    overrides: { 'element': 'span', attributes: { 'data-player-control': 'play' } }
};
```

So basically *overrides* attribute is used when applying background-color and there is a span with such attribute - it is replaced (but then the attribute also gets removed ). You can add *attributes*:

```
config.colorButton_backStyle = {
    element: 'span',
    attributes: { 'data-player-control': 'play' },
    styles: { 'background-color': '#(color)' },
    overrides: { 'element': 'span', attributes: { 'data-player-control': 'play' } }
};
```

So that overriding span also has your attribute. The problem with this solution is that:

1. When applying background color to other elements, `span` will also have `data-player-control` attribute.
2. When removing background color, the whole span gets removed.

---

The above solution may not fit your needs. Maybe there is different approach to the problem you are trying to solve?

As I understand from the question you would like the HTML to have defined structure the whole time (not only as output data), is that correct? What problem is structure with nested spans causing in your application/implementation?

Comment: The items you point out are actually problems for my needs. I edited the question giving more context about the whole picture.

The `data-player-control` attribute has other effects and should not be applied always to elements with background-color set using the colorButton plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying your question, it may also help other users with similar problem. I see you found solution by yourself, that's good;)